# Eclipse crashes during JBOSS startup

Tags: eclipse, jboss, crash, cxf, startup

I am trying to start JBOSS from eclipse. After some time eclipse crashes without showing any error. JBOSS server.log file has following contents:

```
    22:01:29,880 INFO  [org.jboss.as.configadmin] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 25) JBAS016200: Activating ConfigAdmin Subsystem
    22:01:30,073 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) JBAS011940: Activating OSGi Subsystem
    22:01:30,088 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
    22:01:30,114 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 42) JBAS013101: Activating Security Subsystem
    22:01:30,117 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) JBAS014612: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("subsystem" => "webservices")]): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContext.readResourceFromRoot(Lorg/jboss/as/controller/PathAddress;)Lorg/jboss/as/controller/registry/Resource;
        at org.jboss.as.webservices.dmr.WSSubsystemAdd.performBoottime(WSSubsystemAdd.java:132)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractBoottimeAddStepHandler.performRuntime(AbstractBoottimeAddStepHandler.java:57) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractAddStepHandler$1.execute(AbstractAddStepHandler.java:50) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:387) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.doCompleteStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:274) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.completeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:202) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.ParallelBootOperationStepHandler$ParallelBootTask.run(ParallelBootOperationStepHandler.java:311) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_30]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_30]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_30]
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.0.0.GA.jar:2.0.0.GA]

    22:01:30,140 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 29) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
    22:01:30,143 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 36) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
    22:01:30,453 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.7.Final)
    22:01:30,609 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
    22:01:30,610 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS013100: Current PicketBox version=4.0.6.final
    22:01:30,649 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
    22:01:30,712 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBWS022052: Starting JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.2.0.Final
    22:01:30,991 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-4) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080
```

JBOSS boot.log file has following contents:

```
    22:10:52,324 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
    22:10:52,544 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
    22:10:52,619 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.0.Final "Thunder" starting
    22:10:52,621 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.config] Configured system properties:
        awt.toolkit = sun.awt.windows.WToolkit
        file.encoding = Cp1252
        file.encoding.pkg = sun.io
        file.separator = \
        java.awt.graphicsenv = sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment
        java.awt.headless = true
        java.awt.printerjob = sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob
        java.class.path = D:\jboss-as-7.1.0.Final\jboss-modules.jar
        java.class.version = 50.0
        java.endorsed.dirs = C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\endorsed
        java.ext.dirs = C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\ext;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\lib\ext
        java.home = C:\Program Files\Java\jre6
        java.io.tmpdir = C:\Users\176893\AppData\Local\Temp\
        java.library.path = C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;native;C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/lib/i386;C:\Program Files\RSA SecurID Token Common;D:\app\localadmin\product\11.1.0\client_1\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Windows Imaging\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_32\bin;D:\apache-ant-1.8.4\bin;D:\eclipse;;.
        java.net.preferIPv4Stack = true
        java.runtime.name = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
        java.runtime.version = 1.6.0_30-b12
        java.specification.name = Java Platform API Specification
        java.specification.vendor = Sun Microsystems Inc.
        java.specification.version = 1.6
        java.util.logging.manager = org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager
        java.vendor = Sun Microsystems Inc.
        java.vendor.url = http://java.sun.com/
        java.vendor.url.bug = http://java.sun.com/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi
        java.version = 1.6.0_30
        java.vm.info = mixed mode
        java.vm.name = Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
        java.vm.specification.name = Java Virtual Machine Specification
        java.vm.specification.vendor = Sun Microsystems Inc.
        java.vm.specification.version = 1.0
        java.vm.vendor = Sun Microsystems Inc.
        java.vm.version = 20.5-b03
        javax.management.builder.initial = org.jboss.as.jmx.PluggableMBeanServerBuilder
        javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory = __redirected.__DatatypeFactory
        javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory = __redirected.__DocumentBuilderFactory
        javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory = __redirected.__SAXParserFactory
        javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory = __redirected.__XMLEventFactory
        javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory = __redirected.__XMLInputFactory
        javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory = __redirected.__XMLOutputFactory
        javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory = __redirected.__TransformerFactory
        javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory:http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema = __redirected.__SchemaFactory
        javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory:http://java.sun.com/jaxp/xpath/dom = __redirected.__XPathFactory
        jboss.bind.address = localhost
        jboss.home.dir = D:\jboss-as-7.1.0.Final
        jboss.host.name = lt005487
        jboss.modules.dir = D:\jboss-as-7.1.0.Final\modules
        jboss.modules.system.pkgs = org.jboss.byteman
        jboss.node.name = lt005487
        jboss.qualified.host.name = lt005487
        jboss.server.base.dir = D:\jboss-as-7.1.0.Final\standalone
        jboss.server.config.dir = D:\jboss-as-7.1.0.Final\standalone\configuration
        jboss.server.data.dir = D:\jboss-as-7.1.0.Final\standalone\data
        jboss.server.deploy.dir = D:\jboss-as-7.1.0.Final\standalone\data\content
        jboss.server.log.dir = D:\jboss-as-7.1.0.Final\standalone\log
        jboss.server.name = lt005487
        jboss.server.temp.dir = D:\jboss-as-7.1.0.Final\standalone\tmp
        line.separator = 

        logging.configuration = file:/D:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/standalone/configuration/logging.properties
        module.path = D:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/modules
        org.jboss.boot.log.file = D:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/standalone/log/boot.log
        org.jboss.resolver.warning = true
        org.xml.sax.driver = __redirected.__XMLReaderFactory
        os.arch = x86
        os.name = Windows 7
        os.version = 6.1
        path.separator = ;
        sun.arch.data.model = 32
        sun.boot.class.path = C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\sunrsasign.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\modules\jdk.boot.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\classes
        sun.boot.library.path = C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin
        sun.cpu.endian = little
        sun.cpu.isalist = pentium_pro+mmx pentium_pro pentium+mmx pentium i486 i386 i86
        sun.desktop = windows
        sun.io.unicode.encoding = UnicodeLittle
        sun.java.command = org.jboss.modules.Main -mp D:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/modules -jaxpmodule javax.xml.jaxp-provider org.jboss.as.standalone -b localhost --server-config=standalone.xml
        sun.java.launcher = SUN_STANDARD
        sun.jnu.encoding = Cp1252
        sun.management.compiler = HotSpot Client Compiler
        sun.os.patch.level = Service Pack 1
        sun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval = 3600000
        sun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval = 3600000
        user.country = US
        user.dir = D:\jboss-as-7.1.0.Final\bin
        user.home = C:\Users\176893
        user.language = en
        user.name = 176893
        user.timezone = Europe/Berlin
        user.variant = 
    22:10:52,700 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.config] VM Arguments: -Xms64m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=D:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/standalone/log/boot.log -Dlogging.configuration=file:/D:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/standalone/configuration/logging.properties -Djboss.home.dir=D:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 
    22:10:53,828 INFO  [org.xnio] XNIO Version 3.0.3.GA
    22:10:53,828 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
    22:10:53,841 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.3.GA
    22:10:53,850 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] JBoss Remoting version 3.2.2.GA
    22:10:53,878 INFO  [org.jboss.as.configadmin] JBAS016200: Activating ConfigAdmin Subsystem
    22:10:53,887 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] JBAS011502: Removing bootstrap log handlers
```

::::: Edit Start ::::
standalone.xml file has following contents:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

    <server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:1.1">

        <extensions>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan"/>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.configadmin"/>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.connector"/>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.deployment-scanner"/>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.ee"/>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.ejb3"/>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.jaxrs"/>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.jdr"/>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.jmx"/>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.jpa"/>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.logging"/>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.mail"/>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.naming"/>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.osgi"/>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.pojo"/>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.remoting"/>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.sar"/>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.security"/>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.threads"/>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.transactions"/>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.web"/>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.webservices"/>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.weld"/>
        </extensions>

        <management>
            <security-realms>
                <security-realm name="ManagementRealm">
                    <authentication>
                        <properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                    </authentication>
                </security-realm>
                <security-realm name="ApplicationRealm">
                    <authentication>
                        <properties path="application-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                    </authentication>
                </security-realm>
            </security-realms>
            <management-interfaces>
                <native-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm">
                    <socket-binding native="management-native"/>
                </native-interface>
                <http-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm">
                    <socket-binding http="management-http"/>
                </http-interface>
            </management-interfaces>
        </management>

        <profile>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.1">
                <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
                    <level name="INFO"/>
                    <formatter>
                        <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
                    </formatter>
                </console-handler>
                <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE">
                    <formatter>
                        <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
                    </formatter>
                    <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
                    <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
                    <append value="true"/>
                </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
                <logger category="com.arjuna">
                    <level name="WARN"/>
                </logger>
                <logger category="org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler">
                    <level name="WARN"/>
                </logger>
                <logger category="sun.rmi">
                    <level name="WARN"/>
                </logger>
                <logger category="jacorb">
                    <level name="WARN"/>
                </logger>
                <logger category="jacorb.config">
                    <level name="ERROR"/>
                </logger>
                <root-logger>
                    <level name="INFO"/>
                    <handlers>
                        <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                        <handler name="FILE"/>
                    </handlers>
                </root-logger>
            </subsystem>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:configadmin:1.0"/>
            <!--<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.0">
                <datasources>
                    <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                        <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1</connection-url>
                        <driver>h2</driver>
                        <security>
                            <user-name>sa</user-name>
                            <password>sa</password>
                        </security>
                    </datasource>
                    <drivers>
                        <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                            <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                        </driver>
                    </drivers>
                </datasources>
            </subsystem>-->
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:1.1">
                <deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-interval="5000"/>
            </subsystem>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:1.0"/>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:1.2">
                <session-bean>
                    <stateless>
                        <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="slsb-strict-max-pool"/>
                    </stateless>
                    <stateful default-access-timeout="5000" cache-ref="simple"/>
                    <singleton default-access-timeout="5000"/>
                </session-bean>
                <mdb>
                    <resource-adapter-ref resource-adapter-name="hornetq-ra"/>
                    <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="mdb-strict-max-pool"/>
                </mdb>
                <pools>
                    <bean-instance-pools>
                        <strict-max-pool name="slsb-strict-max-pool" max-pool-size="20" instance-acquisition-timeout="5" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>
                        <strict-max-pool name="mdb-strict-max-pool" max-pool-size="20" instance-acquisition-timeout="5" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>
                    </bean-instance-pools>
                </pools>
                <caches>
                    <cache name="simple" aliases="NoPassivationCache"/>
                    <cache name="passivating" passivation-store-ref="file" aliases="SimpleStatefulCache"/>
                </caches>
                <passivation-stores>
                    <file-passivation-store name="file"/>
                </passivation-stores>
                <async thread-pool-name="default"/>
                <timer-service thread-pool-name="default">
                    <data-store path="timer-service-data" relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir"/>
                </timer-service>
                <remote connector-ref="remoting-connector" thread-pool-name="default"/>
                <thread-pools>
                    <thread-pool name="default">
                        <max-threads count="10"/>
                        <keepalive-time time="100" unit="milliseconds"/>
                    </thread-pool>
                </thread-pools>
            </subsystem>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:1.1" default-cache-container="hibernate">
                <cache-container name="hibernate" default-cache="local-query">
                    <local-cache name="entity">
                        <transaction mode="NON_XA"/>
                        <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                        <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
                    </local-cache>
                    <local-cache name="local-query">
                        <transaction mode="NONE"/>
                        <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                        <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
                    </local-cache>
                    <local-cache name="timestamps">
                        <transaction mode="NONE"/>
                        <eviction strategy="NONE"/>
                    </local-cache>
                </cache-container>
            </subsystem>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jaxrs:1.0"/>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jca:1.1">
                <archive-validation enabled="true" fail-on-error="true" fail-on-warn="false"/>
                <bean-validation enabled="false"/>
                <default-workmanager>
                    <short-running-threads>
                        <core-threads count="50"/>
                        <queue-length count="50"/>
                        <max-threads count="50"/>
                        <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
                    </short-running-threads>
                    <long-running-threads>
                        <core-threads count="50"/>
                        <queue-length count="50"/>
                        <max-threads count="50"/>
                        <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
                    </long-running-threads>
                </default-workmanager>
            </subsystem>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jdr:1.0"/>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jmx:1.1">
                <show-model value="true"/>
                <remoting-connector/>
            </subsystem>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jpa:1.0">
                <jpa default-datasource=""/>
            </subsystem>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:mail:1.0">
                <mail-session jndi-name="java:jboss/mail/Default">
                    <smtp-server outbound-socket-binding-ref="mail-smtp"/>
                </mail-session>
            </subsystem>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:1.1"/>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:osgi:1.2" activation="lazy">
                <properties>
                    <!-- Specifies the beginning start level of the framework -->
                    <property name="org.osgi.framework.startlevel.beginning">1</property>
                </properties>
                <capabilities>
                    <!-- modules registered with the OSGi layer on startup -->
                    <capability name="javax.servlet.api:v25"/>
                    <capability name="javax.transaction.api"/>
                    <!-- bundles started in startlevel 1 -->
                    <capability name="org.apache.felix.log" startlevel="1"/>
                    <capability name="org.jboss.osgi.logging" startlevel="1"/>
                    <capability name="org.apache.felix.configadmin" startlevel="1"/>
                    <capability name="org.jboss.as.osgi.configadmin" startlevel="1"/>
                </capabilities>
            </subsystem>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:pojo:1.0"/>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:remoting:1.1">
                <connector name="remoting-connector" socket-binding="remoting" security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
            </subsystem>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:1.0"/>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:sar:1.0"/>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.1">
                <security-domains>
                    <security-domain name="other" cache-type="default">
                        <authentication>
                            <login-module code="Remoting" flag="optional">
                                <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                            </login-module>
                            <login-module code="RealmUsersRoles" flag="required">
                                <module-option name="usersProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/application-users.properties"/>
                                <module-option name="rolesProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/application-roles.properties"/>
                                <module-option name="realm" value="ApplicationRealm"/>
                                <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                            </login-module>
                        </authentication>
                    </security-domain>
                    <security-domain name="jboss-web-policy" cache-type="default">
                        <authorization>
                            <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
                        </authorization>
                    </security-domain>
                    <security-domain name="jboss-ejb-policy" cache-type="default">
                        <authorization>
                            <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
                        </authorization>
                    </security-domain>
                </security-domains>
            </subsystem>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:threads:1.1"/>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:transactions:1.1">
                <core-environment>
                    <process-id>
                        <uuid/>
                    </process-id>
                </core-environment>
                <recovery-environment socket-binding="txn-recovery-environment" status-socket-binding="txn-status-manager"/>
                <coordinator-environment default-timeout="300"/>
            </subsystem>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
                <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
                <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
                    <alias name="localhost"/>
                    <alias name="example.com"/>
                </virtual-server>
            </subsystem>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:webservices:1.1">
                <modify-wsdl-address>true</modify-wsdl-address>
                <wsdl-host>${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}</wsdl-host>
                <endpoint-config name="Standard-Endpoint-Config"/>
                <endpoint-config name="Recording-Endpoint-Config">
                    <pre-handler-chain name="recording-handlers" protocol-bindings="##SOAP11_HTTP ##SOAP11_HTTP_MTOM ##SOAP12_HTTP ##SOAP12_HTTP_MTOM">
                        <handler name="RecordingHandler" class="org.jboss.ws.common.invocation.RecordingServerHandler"/>
                    </pre-handler-chain>
                </endpoint-config>
            </subsystem>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:weld:1.0"/>
        </profile>

        <interfaces>
            <interface name="management">
                <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>
            </interface>
            <interface name="public">
                <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>
            </interface>
        </interfaces>

        <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
            <socket-binding name="http" port="8080"/>
            <socket-binding name="https" port="8443"/>
            <socket-binding name="management-native" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.native.port:9999}"/>
            <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
            <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9443}"/>
            <socket-binding name="osgi-http" interface="management" port="8090"/>
            <socket-binding name="remoting" port="4447"/>
            <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
            <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
            <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
                <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
            </outbound-socket-binding>
        </socket-binding-group>
    </server>
```

:::: Edit End ::::

I am using Eclipse Juno. OS is windows 7. JDK is 1.6.032. JBOSS is jboss-as-7.1.0.Final. JBOSS is plased at location "D:\jboss-as-7.1.0.Final".

Please let me know, what is wrong here.

::::::::::::: EDIT 4 Sept 2013 :::::::::::::::::

What I observed was JBOSS crashes only after APACHE CXF is installed on my JBOSS APP. Without APACHE CXF, JBOSS starts from eclipse. To install APACHE CXF, I modified ant.properties file for CXF with following two properties:

```
jboss712.home=D:\\jboss-as-7.1.0.Final
jbossws.integration.target=jboss712
```

And I executed ANT target:

```
ant -Dspring=true deploy-jboss712
```

Could it be the problem that I have JBOSS 7.1.0 and I am telling APACHE CXF that its JBOSS 7.1.2?
Version of APACHE CFX is jbossws-cxf-4.2.0.Final. Please let me know if you require more information.

Comment: Have you tried the same test with Eclipse Kepler?

Comment: No I have not. But i found that installation of APACHE CXF causes JBOSS to crash. Please refer to my updates in question. Weird thing is that, I am not able to find anywhere references to this exception shown in the logs.